# Failed to instantiate module maq

Tags: angularjs

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
//app.js

'use strict';

var app = angular.module('maq', [
  'ui.router',
  'maq.home.controller'
]).run([
    '$rootScope',
    '$state',
    '$stateParams', function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams){
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
      $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
  }])
  .config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
          controller: 'maq.home.controller'
        })
  }]);

//controller
'use strict';

app
  .controller('maq.home.controller', [function(){

  }]);


//error
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module maq due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module maq.home.controller due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'maq.home.controller' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually do not have a module called `maq.home.controller` Instead your registration is in such a way that it is the controller name.

If you want to separate your controller to another module (as what you are trying to do)

try:-

```
angular.module('maq.controller', []); //<-- Module creation
//...
angular.module('maq.controller')
        .controller('HomeController', [function() { //<-- Controller registration

}]);
```

and in your app:-

```
var app = angular.module('maq', [
  'ui.router',
  'maq.controller' //<-- Controller mmodule
]);
```

Or just remove the dependency on the module that does not exist:-

```
angular.module('maq', [
  'ui.router',
  //'maq.home.controller' <-- Remove this
])
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to depend on another module named maq.home.controller when it is not a module, it is a controller. You do not need to list controllers as dependencies in your module declaration. So just take that dependency out like so:

```
var app = angular.module('maq', [
  'ui.router'
])
```